# How to fetch the timestamps at which each user speaks?

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm working on a project and would like to know if there is a way to obtain the timestamps at which a speaker speaks in a YouTube video.

For example,

If a video involves 3 persons speaking back and forth, the method/function could return something like

```
{
    'speaker1': ['00:09-01:04', '01:15-05:12'],
    'speaker2': ['08:00-09:02', '15:15-20:12'],
    'speaker3': ['10:19-11:04', '25:10-35:17'],
}
```

A solution in python would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You could parse the auto-generated captions, and get the start/end timestamps and speaker name for each dialogue line.

Comment: Thanks! What about the videos that do not have any captions? I reckon downloading and processing it would not be feasible

Comment: hmm, you could look into a captioning service that offers auto-generated or human generated captions for YT videos, but I wonder if that might be a bit of overkill for this use case however.

Comment: You could also look into a managed service like [AWS Transcribe](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/latest/dg/diarization.html) which appears to do what you want. In this case looks like you'd need to pass in the audio track for the video, then you'd get an API response with speaker names and dialogue timestamps.

Comment: @rv.kvetch Awesome. I'll look into it